# Android: Users with certain devices cannot use my application's web-services - SSLPeerUnverifiedException

Tags: java, android, https

I have an application which interacts over https with a server I have. I have a valid certificate.

The application works fine for most users, but some users are reporting that they have problems connecting with their rooted devices. They are also reporting with the HTC Evo 2.3.3, with the upgrade from Sprint, the application has the same behavior.

I borrowed a friends' Evo, and was able to get the following stack-trace below. I have seen solutions for this which are basically 'accept all certs' but that is not possible since I am releasing this in production.

Has anyone seen a fix for this? Possibly storing my server's cert directly on the device?

```
06-24 15:15:52.051: WARN/ServiceOperation(1535): javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
06-24 15:15:52.051: WARN/ServiceOperation(1535):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:258)
06-24 15:15:52.051: WARN/ServiceOperation(1535):     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
06-24 15:15:52.051: WARN/ServiceOperation(1535):     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:381)
06-24 15:15:52.051: WARN/ServiceOperation(1535):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:164)
06-24 15:15:52.051: WARN/ServiceOperation(1535):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-24 15:15:52.051: WARN/ServiceOperation(1535):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-24 15:15:52.051: WARN/ServiceOperation(1535):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
06-24 15:15:52.051: WARN/ServiceOperation(1535):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-24 15:15:52.051: WARN/ServiceOperation(1535):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-24 15:15:52.051: WARN/ServiceOperation(1535):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
```

Comment: Can you list the site in the question? Taking a look at the certificate might help.

Comment: No, sorry. Client has a lot of security concerns. I can say, however that the server has a verisign certificate that works fine on most devices, and every browser I've tried.

Comment: That's enough for me. I suspected you were using CAcert.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I'm seeing the same issue from HTC Wildfire S devices, and no fix in sight from HTC.

Comment: @NikReiman No. We changed our server certificate to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems related to a issue HTC created when they released 2.3.3. There's a bug report about it here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16885#c7

I'm going to hold off on hardcoding anything into the application, So I guess for now I won't support these users.